# iTextSharp unintended scaling up of image when document is in portrait mode

Tags: c#, itext

Using iTextSharp version 4.1.6, I'm adding a logo to the top left corner of my pdf document like this.

```
public MemoryStream GeneratePdf(bool landscapeMode)
    {
        // Create the iTextSharp document.
        var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 25, 25);
        if(landscapeMode) {
           //set to landscape mode
           doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        }
        // Set the document to write to memory.
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();

        //get logo
        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images/Logo.png"));
        // set position in document
        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.LeftMargin, doc.PageSize.Height - doc.TopMargin - logo.Height);
        //insert logo
        doc.Add(logo);

        // Add other stuff ...

        // Close and return memory stream
        doc.Close();
        return memStream;
    }
```

The logo is displayed properly (in its original size) as long as `landscapeMode` is set to true, but when `landscapeMode` is set to false (portrait mode), the logo is upscaled about 150%. How do I stop this unintended up-scaling in portrait mode?

Comment: You are using a version of iTextSharp that is 6 years old. Many updates have been released since 2009. The version you are using is no longer supported. Please don't expect an answer or a solution if you don't upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand that version 4.1.6 is pretty old. Was it not for change in licensing in newer versions, I'd use the current version. It's a small non-profit project I'm doing so I can't justify spending $2200 for a license + for security reasons, can't make it open source. I was hoping someone may point out a mistake in my code, but from your comment I take it it's a bug in this version